# Retrieve Firebase Object id

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using the following loop to get data from a table which is working fine:

```
database.once("value", function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    log.console(snap.val().about_me)
})
```

Its displaying the data to logs as expected, But i can't seem to get the object id?

I need to get the value `49GRZb8B31MUfpBN3zvHKOHCMOa2`

[image]

I have tried:

```
snap.val().key;
```

This returns undefined

And have tried `snap.val()[0];`

which returns me everything in the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snap` is a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) type object.  You can see that it has a property called [key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#key).  So, you need to reference that property directly on the DataSnapshot like this:

```
snap.key  // correct
```

But **not** via the raw data object like this:

```
snap.val().key   // incorrect, you have no child named 'key' in your data
```